# for loops and while loops - i

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to extract some data from thousands of text files. I have problem extracting the specific information from the files. 
That is, if I have a list,

list = [manager ,A, B, C, analyst, F, G, H, Operator, 7, 8]

and want to have a two list :
m_list= [A, B, C]
a_list = [F, G, H]

Could someone tell me where my problem is?  Thank you.

I have tried the following code, but I stuck in the first while loop,infinite loop.

```py
ff = [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7,8]
mm = []
aa = []
for i in ff :
    while i == 1:
        print(i)
        mm.append(i)
        while i == 4:
            break
    while i == 4:
        aa.append(i)
        while i == 7:
            break
```

Comment: Your logic is not clear you will fall in an infinite loop.
what's output should be using this `list [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7,8]`?

Comment: yes, I fell in the infinite loop. I want to have to list. One:[2,3] Two:[5,6]

Comment: You could clarify if 1, 4 and 7 are input parameters (as "split the original list at these values")

Answer (score 0):

As per you question and desire output from `ff = [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7,8]` converting into `list1 = [2,3] list = 2[5,6]` two list, what I understand that you wants to skip the every 3rd item starting from 1st. IF so then you can iterate over the length of original list with using `step=3`.

```
ff = [1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7,8]
output = []
for i in range(1, len(ff), 3):
    output.append(ff[i:i+2])
```

Here your output list will contain all the list based on your requirement

```
>>> output                                                                                        
[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't attack this problem with a for-while-append loop. Look at list "slices" or "list comprehension" instead. For instance:

```
start = ff.index(1)+1
end = ff.index(4)
ff[start:end]
```

(this one would work with your list that contains strings)

Or list-comprehension:

```
>>> [ i for i in ff if 1<i<4 ]
[2, 3]
>>> [ i for i in ff if 4<i<7 ]
[5, 6]
```